# problems with dectection of camera while using the SARXOS api in java

Tags: java, ubuntu, camera

```
Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
if (webcam != null) {
        System.out.println("Webcam: " + webcam.getName());
} else {
    System.out.println("No webcam detected");
}
```

I am facing problem with the exception describe below while using the SARXOS Webcam api.
I am using the ACER Laptop with the webcam and Ubuntu 12 Os.

Stacktrace:

```
 [main] INFO com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam - WebcamDefaultDriver capture driver will be used
Exception in thread "main" com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryService.getWebcams(WebcamDiscoveryService.java:118)
at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.getWebcams(Webcam.java:692)
at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.getDefault(Webcam.java:755)
at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.getDefault(Webcam.java:732)
at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.getDefault(Webcam.java:710)
at com.convoy.gpack.pack.DetectWebcamExample.main(DetectWebcamExample.java:7)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamDiscoveryService.getWebcams(WebcamDiscoveryService.java:110)
... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception means that before I executed the code I haven't added required JARs into the Java classpath (specifically bridj-*.jar):

First of all I must have to add all required jar into to project and I did it...It works

Thanks a lot SARXOS

~Problem Solved